# Padding with a prefix characters to always have a 12 character string

Tags: c#

I'm working with numbers stored in a string in C#.

I have some number such as `22408061`. I would like to add dynamic 0 characters to have 12 characters giving `000022408061`.

As another example, given `12322408061`, it needs to be `012322408061`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [everything](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=c%23+pad+with+zeros). (Note to self: get 100+k reputation by answering obvious duplicate questions.)

Comment: Please consider that the asker propably did not know about the term "padding" to find the correct answer. At least for me as non-native speaker this wasn't clear when I didn't know yet about padding.

Comment: [Extra zeroes](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=c%23+extra+zeros)?

Comment: Do you have number to begin with or is it a string containing number ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for [`PadLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method.

```
var str = "22408061".PadLeft(12, '0');
```

Answer (score 2):

> This is a string in c#.

You can use [`PadLeft`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string text = "22408061";
text = text.PadLeft(12, '0'); // 000022408061
```

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92h5dc07(v=vs.110).aspx

Console.WriteLine(str.PadLeft(12, pad));

Answer (score 0):

Logic is :

1. count the number of length, say for eg in 22408061 you will get 8 length
2. subtract 12 - 8 = 4 i.e. total value - length
3. which ever number you get, add that many zeros before the number.